# rails asset pipeline: Invalid CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use http://designshack.net/articles/css/build-an-animated-photo-wall-with-css/ 
to implement a photo wall in my rails app. I plugged the CSS for list, paragraph and image, with the only changes in image height and width into my custom.css.scss like so:

```
/* picture wall */

/*------CONTAINER------*/
.container {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
}

/*------LIST------*/
.container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
 
.container li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
  height: 187px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 
.container li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*------PARAGRAPH------*/
.container li p {
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  font: 200 10px/80px 'Arvo', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
   
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px; 
 
 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
 
.container li:hover p {
  color: white;
  background: #000; /*fallback for old browsers*/
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

/*------IMAGES------*/
.container img {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
   
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
 
.container li:hover img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

The asset pipeline throws the following error in that file:

```
Invalid CSS after "  position:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " absolute;"
```

Commenting out the position line brings up the next line in the file:

```
Invalid CSS after "  top:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " 0;"
```

A syntax problem? Can I not simply put valid css into an scss file? What gives?

Comment: Can you post more of your CSS code?

Comment: Please show us your css.

Comment: @vinodadhikary just edited to add the CSS I copied and changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing whitespaces below the line with `text-transform: uppercase;`.

Comment: you are right, that is the problem, just found it myself. thx!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the blank lines! Removed and it does not throw an error. Jeez, blank lines are invalid CSS or SASS???

(The code still doesn't do what it should, but that is an entirely different issue :-)

Comment: It depends on what the whitespace character in question is.  There are a few different characters that resemble spaces, newlines, tabs, etc. that aren't actually valid characters.