# How to find a CSS error from application.css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When precompiling assets locally, I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
  (in   /Users/nicholas/Documents/sites/ico/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):33123
```

My problem is I have no idea how or where to track this down.  I have over 30 individual CSS files, and it could be coming from any one of them.

Is there any way to find this compiled application.css file and actually see the line of code to determine where this error is coming from?

Comment: Isn't it in `/Users/nicholas/Documents/sites/ico/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`?

Comment: CSS has a pretty clear syntax. You could look the file up, which sawa stated in his comment. IMO this makes more sense than checking the compiled CSS. - You could of course use a validator to fix the error: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: @sawa - No, its not there.  Application.css in a rails app is only a manifest file and doesn't contain any CSS code.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954541/rails-asset-pipeline-invalid-css

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to track the bug is to switch off the precompiling in development mode, so the files wouldn't be joined into one application.css

try this in config/environments/development.rb :

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

Comment: just checked my development.rb, and those settings were already in place.

Comment: @Bogdan Agafonov - I tried that too, but there's no application.css file in the public/assets.  I also tried the cmd-shift-f trick already, but if you look at my specific error, it only shows a single bracket as the error.  This is incredibly vague and doesn't help me pinpoint the bug at all.

Comment: @jmromer - I promise.  There's an application.js file in there, but not an application.css.  I found that strange as well. I think this might be because of the precompilation error, but I dont know.