# In Rails Rspec gives an invalid css error but the app works fine. How to fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sass, capybara

When I run rspec, it gives me an erro like this

```
  1) AuthenticationPages sign in page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit dash_signin_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Invalid CSS after "...weight: normal ": expected ";", was "!!important;"
         (in /home/pubudu/Projects/sumaga-asapuwa/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
     # (sass):1453
     # ./app/views/layouts/_head.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts__head_html_erb___1666364908545837178_48771360'
     # ./app/views/layouts/sessions.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_sessions_html_erb___2365426594570869078_49324500'
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The problem is, I haven't used `font-weight: normal` in my css! How can I pin point the exact problem? I removed all the custom css I added but still the problem is there. Is it zurb foundation?

Comment: I'm assuming you've gone through the browser sources to find the line in the compiled stylesheets? That's where I'd start. It'd show you where rules are coming from and why they're overriding each other

Comment: might be worth to check if it is a whitespace issue like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954541/rails-asset-pipeline-invalid-css

Answer (score 0):

A jquery plugin I used had a css issue! It used `!!important`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't find in the W3C CSS specifications that `!!important` is allowed (see http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#importance).

I'm not a sass expert, but to me it seems that `!!important` is the error that rspec is pointing out.

By the way, the file in which you have an error is a normal css file (css extension instead of scss).

Try using `!important` instead!